# How to programatically move a Linux symlink to a different file system (copy) in C?

Tags: c, symlink

rename() C function does not work across file systems. So I can move files via a copy by opening them, reading them and writing them to a new copy and then unlinking. But I have a hard time getting this to work with symlinks. (The idea is to move a folder with a bunch of other files/folders/symlinks etc inside of it). Basically implementing a mv command in C.

```
open(file, O_RDONLY)
while ((c = read(source_descriptor, buf, SIZE)) > 0){
        write(d, buf, c);
}
unlink file;
```

Works good for normal files (and I have another function handling directories without issues). But whenever it hits a symlink I get **perror** spitting out *No such file or directory*.

I can detect if its a symlink via **d_type** but am not sure how to read/copy it once I have one since the normal file copy doesnt seem to work with symlinks because open() refuses to open them.

Comment: Wouldn't be more efficient invoking a shell command through `system` or `execl` ?

Comment: Yes, but the idea is to implement mv in C. So any kind of system()/exec call would be cheating :)

Comment: Just a general hint, it'd be good if you provided actual valid C code, a compilable program which you have tested to actually reproduce the problem, if at all possible. This is called MCVE, check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have determined that you're dealing with a symlink (which can be done e.g. by using [`lstat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html)), you can read its contents with [`readlink()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) and recreate it at the target location by calling [`symlink()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html).

See also [`man 7 symlink`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html).

Comment: excellent. Ill give this a shot... I knew about lstat, but not about symlink(). Ill need to look into that to see how it works. Thanks! If this solves it Ill come back and mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: Beautiful! This made it easier than I thought it would be. Just needed to be pointed in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you `open` a symlink without the `O_NOFOLLOW` flag, it will dereference the symlink (or symlink chain, if it's a symlink to a symlink). If the destination does not exist, open will fail. The `O_NOFOLLOW` flag makes sure, that if you attempt to open a symlink you will realiably get an error.

To "copy" a symlink, you'll have to read it with `readlink` and create a new symlink at the destination. However you may have to adjust the path it points to.

*However* if a program of yours has the need to copy directory trees on a *nix system, the correct way to implement this is not to reinvent the wheel, but to follow the Unix way and just execute the `cp` program with the right arguments.